# How to obtain algebraic solution of a logarithmic equation. (mathematica)

Tags: equation-solving

How to obtain algebraic solution of the logarithmic equation

```
expression=-b n + Exp[t] lambda n
Solve[ expression == 0, t]
```

The output should be $$t=Ln \left(\frac{b}{lambda}\right)$$, but I get.

```
{{t -> ConditionalExpression[2 I \[Pi] C[1] + Log[b/lambda], 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell Mathematica (`Element[t,Reals]`)  what you are looking for (and change `e^t` to `Exp[t]` )

```
expression = -b  + Exp[t] lambda  
Solve[expression == 0, t, Reals]
{{t -> ConditionalExpression[Log[b/lambda], (b > 0 && lambda > 0) || (b < 0 && lambda < 0)]}}
```

Comment: what I posted is an MWE, it is not the real problem. In the real problem, I do not know the final answer. So, I can not tell Mathematica what I am looking for. 

My question would be then "If I do not know the solution of an equation, how to find this solution using Mathematica?"

Comment: What I meant is if you know you're looking for a **real**  solution use `Solve[…, Reals]`

Comment: This response is simple and goes directly to the question that was asked. If it is not adequate, that indicates something amiss in the question.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Right thanks you!!!! I wonder, how can I extract the solution and save it as a new variable x_new=Solve[ expression == 0, t]

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Perhaps ` tnew=(t /. sol)[[1, 1]]` as a workaround?